# Pandas DataFrame, turn index and its name into column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wanted to create DataFrame with 2 columns, one called 'id' , one called 'SalePrice'

```
submission = pd.DataFrame({'SalePrice':pre})
```

It looks like this

```
    SalePrice
0   183242.025920
1   188796.451732
2   187878.763989
3   179789.672031
```

I know that I can name the index, but I need instead name it as a normal column name, on the same level as SalePrice. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: the first column always is the index either named or unnamed. If you need 2 columns, just `reset_index` and `rename` it to `id`. The output will be 1 index column and 2 data columns

Answer (score 0):

Try create it with `DataFrame` constructor

```
submission = pd.DataFrame({'SalePrice':pre,'id':np.arange(len(per))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reset_index`, same as @Andy L. suggested. here's the full code:

```
submission = pd.DataFrame({'SalePrice':[1,2,3,4]}).reset_index()
submission.rename(columns = {'index':'id'}, inplace=True)
print(submission)
```

The output:

```
   id   SalePrice
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
```